# Creating a simple chrome extension that searches a Google Sheet Column A and returns the associated value in Column B

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

this seems to be a common topic that comes up - but can't find a verified answer.

I am trying to make a simple Chrome extension that will download all values from a Google Sheet in Column A and Column B and return the value as a table.

I  have managed to get a simple textfield and button to show up as an extension - but can't seem to to get it to connect to the Google Sheets Api.

Any guidance would be most welcome.

Interface popuphtml.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Google Sheets Search</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Google Sheets Search</h1>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter value to search">
  <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Popup.js

```
  document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', searchValue);
});

function searchValue() {
  var searchValue = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
  
  // Send a message to the background script to execute content script
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "searchValue", searchValue: searchValue});
}

// Listener for receiving response from background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "displayResult") {
    displayResult(message.result);
  }
});

function displayResult(result) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('result');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = result;
}
```

Background.js:

```
    if (message.action === "searchValue") {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
          function: function(searchValue) {
         <! search function removed >
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
              chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "displayResult", result: result});
            }).searchValue(searchValue);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
  

  function searchValue(value) {
    var spreadsheetId = '<hidden>';
    var range = 'Sheet1!A:B';
    var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range);
    var values = response.values;
    if (!values) {
      return 'No data found.';
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i][0] == value) {
          return 'Value found: ' + values[i][0] + ', ' + values[i][1];
        }
      }
      return 'Value not found.';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Add `world: 'MAIN'` to executeScript and use return+result instead of chrome.runtime.sendMessage, [example](/a/46870005). The `function` can return `new Promise` if the sheets API is asynchronous so you can use resolve() in its callback.